# Is there an option to autocomplete with first character in intellij idea or android studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, autocomplete

As everyone knows, we love using auto-complete.
Can we turn on autocomplete with tab key without entering the first character for the parentheses?
[autocomplete keywords in the setting panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJjYj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shortcuts in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`. For invoking code completion: `Main menu | Code | Code Completion | Basic`.

Note that you might get shortcut conflicts.